# How to compute matrix transpose using OpenBlas's cblas_somatcopy?

Tags: matrix, transpose, openblas

This is my first experience with a blas-like, and I'm having some dificulties to understand how to use OpenBlas cblas_somatcopy(...). I'm trying to transpose A, a 10x10 matrix, and store it into matrix B (also 10x10).

The code used was:

```
float* A = malloc(sizeof(float)*10*10);
float* B = malloc(sizeof(float)*10*10);

/*Initialize Matrix A*/
...
cblas_somatcopy(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, 10, 10, 1.0f, A, 10, B, 10);
```

After calling cblas_somatcopy matrix B remains unchanged (only zeroes). Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by including the proper cblas.h header file.